# Link two object files using gcc

Tags: c, windows, object, gcc

I would like to link two object files, but when I use 
**gcc -m32 file1.o file2.s -o output_file** (I read somewhere that assembly files do not have to be compile to objects)
it gets errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for
-lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching  for
-lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for
-lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for
-lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannotfind -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../libcygwin.a when searching for -lcygwin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lcygwin /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -ladvapi32 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lshell32 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -luser32 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lkernel32 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for
-lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for
-lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for
-lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc_s.dll.a when searching for
-lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc_s /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3//libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/libgcc.a when searching for - lgcc /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.3/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -lgcc collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I know I am clearly missing something but no idea where to get those missing files. Can anyone help me? 
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please format your compiler messages using the **code block** formatting, now that is an unreadable mess.

Comment: The files are already on your PC because the compiler error states: _skipping incompatible ..._ all the time. The compiler founds only 64-bit libraries, but you are requesting to compile a 32-bit binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are using `-m32` on a 64bit machine.`-m32` is -m32 is for compiling 32 bit objects when the compiler is configured, by default, to compile 64 bits objects.

The error is occurring because you don't have the 32bit version of the standard library installed.

By removing `-m32`, to get `gcc file1.o file2.s -o output_file`, you stop asking the compile to link two 64bit objects as a 32bit executable, and the resultant executable is then 64bit (as configured by default).

However, if you really want 32bit, then you should compile your objects using `-m32`. You will also need to make sure that you have the relevant 32bit standard library

Comment: Yes I want it to be compiled as 32 bit, I tried complile objects using -m32 but it gets the same errors

Comment: @Paul As I stated in my answer, "The error is occurring because you don't have the 32bit version of the standard library installed." I'll edit the answer to make this more clear